# I am getting white label error with 404 (not found) while I am loging in

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-security, authorization

Here is my code for security configuration, I am getting white label error with 404 (not found) when I mention roles in `hasAnyAuthority` method, but when I mention only one role in `hasAuthority` it is working fine. Here I need to know do we need any authentication manager bean or authentication manager builder bean?

```java
@EnableWebSecurity
@Configuration
public class WebSecurityConfig {
    
    @Bean
    public UserDetailsService userDetailsService() {
        return new UserDetailsServiceImpl();
    }

    @Bean
    AuthenticationProvider authenticationProvider() {
        DaoAuthenticationProvider authProvider = new DaoAuthenticationProvider();
        authProvider.setUserDetailsService(userDetailsService());
        authProvider.setPasswordEncoder(passwordEncoder());

        return authProvider;
    }

    @Bean
    public BCryptPasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }

    @Bean
    SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http    
            .cors()
                .and()
            .csrf().disable()
            .authorizeHttpRequests()
                .antMatchers("/register").permitAll()
                .and()
            .authorizeHttpRequests()
                .antMatchers("/signin").hasAnyAuthority("ROLE_ADMIN", "ROLE_USER")
                .and()
            .formLogin()
                .permitAll()
                .and()
            .authenticationProvider(authenticationProvider());

        return http.build();
    }
}
```

Below is my controller class, I have not created any HTML pages. I am simply displaying message to check weather it is working or not, but it is not working. While I am mentioning the two roles which is user and admin in `hasAnyAuthority` and when I hit the `/signin` URL it is not working.

```java
@RestController
public class UserRegistrationController {

    @Autowired
    private UserServices userService;

    @Autowired
    private PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder;

    @PostMapping("/register")
    public ResponseEntity<User> createUser(@Valid @RequestBody User user) throws Throwable {
        String tempEmailID = user.getEmailId();
        String encryptedPassword = passwordEncoder.encode(user.getPassword());
        user.setPassword(encryptedPassword);
        if (tempEmailID != null && !"".equals(tempEmailID)) {
            User userObject = userService.fetchUserByEmailId(tempEmailID);
            if (userObject != null) {
                throw new ResourceNotFoundException("User with " + tempEmailID + " is already exist ");
            }
            userService.save(user);
        }

        return new ResponseEntity<User>(user, HttpStatus.CREATED);
    }

    @GetMapping("/signin")
    public String loginPage() {
        return "login sucess";
    }
}
```

Comment: just so you know, you dont need to define the DaoAuthenticationProvider manually, if you supply a PasswordEncoder and a UserDetailsService as beans spring security will create the provider for you automatically. Also please provide your request, we have no idea what your request looks like, how can we know are we supposed to guess?

Comment: What URL do you call? Did you call `/login` or `signin`? Do you get the 404 before or after you logged in?

Comment: I used to call signin url, I am getting after error 404 after login